# java and database connection

Tags: java, sql, swing

I'm having a problem in my project i cant Connect the program with the data Source

So if there's any help plzz assist me

this is the error message and the source code below

I'm in trouble plzzz help meeeeee

```
//for creating the North Panel
    private JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
    //for creating the Center Panel
    private JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
    //for creating the label
    private JLabel northLabel = new JLabel("THE LIST FOR THE BOOKS");
    //for creating the button
    private JButton printButton;
    //for creating the table
    private JTable table;
    //for creating the TableColumn
    private TableColumn column = null;
    //for creating the JScrollPane
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    //for creating an object for the ResultSetTableModel class
    private ResultSetTableModel tableModel;

    /***************************************************************************
     * for setting the required information for the ResultSetTableModel class. *
     ***************************************************************************/
    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
    private static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:odbc:Telecom";
    private static final String DEFAULT_QUERY = "SELECT EmployeeID,EmployeeName,ProjectName,JobTitle,MobileNumber,DateOfSim,SimNumber,MCG,Active  FROM [Telecom].[dbo].[Employee];";


    //constructor of listBooks
    public ListBooks() {
        //for setting the title for the internal frame
        super("Employee", false, true, false, true);
        //for setting the icon
        setFrameIcon(new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/List16.gif")));
        setLocale(new java.util.Locale("ar", "SA", ""));

        //for getting the graphical user interface components displaygvk area
        Container cp = getContentPane();

        //for bassing the required information to the ResultSetTableModel object
        try {
            tableModel = new ResultSetTableModel(JDBC_DRIVER, DATABASE_URL, DEFAULT_QUERY);
            //for setting the Query
            try {
                tableModel.setQuery(DEFAULT_QUERY);
            }
            catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFound) {
            System.out.println(classNotFound.toString());
        }
        catch (SQLException sqlException) {
            System.out.println(sqlException.toString());
        }
        //for setting the table with the information
        table = new JTable(tableModel);
        //for setting the size for the table
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(990, 200));
        //for setting the font
        table.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        //for setting the scrollpane to the table
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        //for setting the size for the table columns
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

            column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            if (i == 0) //BookID
            column.setPreferredWidth(20);
            if (i == 1) //Subject
                column.setPreferredWidth(100);
            if (i == 2) //Title
                column.setPreferredWidth(150);
            if (i == 3) //Auther
                column.setPreferredWidth(50);
            if (i == 4) //Publisher
                column.setPreferredWidth(70);
            if (i == 5) //Copyright
                column.setPreferredWidth(40);
            if (i == 6) //Edition
                column.setPreferredWidth(40);
            if (i == 7) //Pages
                column.setPreferredWidth(40);
            if (i == 8) //NumberOfBooks
                column.setPreferredWidth(80);


               }
        //for setting the font to the label
        northLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        //for setting the layout to the panel
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        //for adding the label to the panel
        northPanel.add(northLabel);
        //for adding the panel to the container
        cp.add("North", northPanel);

        //for setting the layout to the panel
        centerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //for creating an image for the button
        ImageIcon printIcon = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/Print16.gif"));
        //for adding the button to the panel
        printButton = new JButton("print the books", printIcon);
        //for setting the tip text
        printButton.setToolTipText("Print");
        //for setting the font to the button
        printButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        //for adding the button to the panel
        centerPanel.add(printButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //for adding the scrollpane to the panel
        centerPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //for setting the border to the panel
        centerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Books:"));
        //for adding the panel to the container
        cp.add("Center", centerPanel);

        //for adding the actionListener to the button
        printButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                Thread runner = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            PrinterJob prnJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
                            prnJob.setPrintable(new PrintingBooks(DEFAULT_QUERY));
                            if (!prnJob.printDialog())
                                return;
                            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
                            prnJob.print();
                            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
                        }
                        catch (PrinterException ex) {
                            System.out.println("Printing error: " + ex.toString());
                        }
                    }
                };
                runner.start();
            }
        });
        //for setting the visible to true
        setVisible(true);
        //to show the frame
        pack();
    }
}
```

I got the following error

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string
>   or buffer length

Comment: Where abouts in the code is the exception generated?

Comment: dont know wht u mean

Comment: Post detailed stack trace.

Comment: The error message you have, should have included at "stack trace" listing the methods, source code and line numbers from where the error originated from.  We will need this and the location in the code that the error originated from...

Comment: 1- Instead of using `System.out.println(sqlException.toString());`, use `sqlException.printStackTrace()`; 2- Don't ignore exceptions

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(JdbcOdbc.java:3906)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:5697)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(JdbcOdbcResultSet.java:353)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.buildTypeInfo(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:1503)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:381)

Comment: at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:243)
 at ResultSetTableModel.<init>(ResultSetTableModel.java:26)
 at ListBooks.<init>(ListBooks.java:59)
 at JLibrary$3.run(JLibrary.java:159)

Comment: So the error originates within your `ResultSetTableModel` constructor, line 26...going to need to see that...and this information should be added to your question

Comment: this is line 26>>>>connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url); // connect to database

Comment: @MidooOusman: Edit your question to include hose new results.

Comment: Not working Experts plzzz help

Comment: guys I think there is a problem with my JDBC ODBC connection how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
    column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i+1);
```

instead of this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
    column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
```

Maybe it works.